# Using urllib3 to fetch JSON data

Tags: python, json, urllib3

I have written my own URL shortener in PHP and now am trying to develop a python frontend for it. My python script is as follows:

```
import certifi
import urllib3
import json
manager = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs=certifi.where())
url = input("Please enter a URL: ")
short = manager.request("GET", "https://www.get-short.net/feed.php?i=" + url)
data = short.read(decode_content=True)
print(json.loads(data))
```

and, when I run it, I get the following output when I type in a URL

```
c:\Projects>python short.py
Please enter a URL: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "short.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(json.loads(data))
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I know the problem is either my code or my JSON output but what do I have to do to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use `short.data` instead of `short.read`

what type does short.read return?

Comment: Just returns an empty string

Comment: When I edit short.read to be short.data, I get a TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: Hi @WillRichards

I just ran your code with python and `json.loads(short.data.decode('utf-8'))` works for me and reads the correct json.

short.data returns bytes which i then decode with utf-8. After that read it as a string and load it.